# Grails and multitenancy

Tags: mysql, grails, plugins, multi-tenant

I have to use **multitenant** plugin in grails, but I need one DB type (mySL) but several schemas, not only one, one each client, for reliability reasons, and I think that plugin multitenant-single-db is not correct. Am I right? Do I need multitenant-core?

Comment: Yes. Multi-tenant might not suffice you need. You could have look at http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/single.html#multipleDatasources

Comment: Thanks very much. Not yet sure, but multitenant-single-db could be enough. The core plugin is no more supported and single-db was born on core... I need to study more the documentation.